# Proxy request getting errors

Tags: python, python-requests, proxies

Hi i'm trying to use different proxy to scrape this [website][1], 
But i'm keep getting errors.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import urllib3

url2= 'https://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.96746500000006&lon=-118.25679999999994#.XphNUsgzaUk'

proxies1 = {
    "https": "https://209.220.97.131:8080",
    "http": "http://209.220.97.131:8080"
}

page = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies1, verify=False)
```

**And this is the error i'm getting:**

```
C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Scraper/Clever scraper.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 667, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 930, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 308, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BED2B7E388>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 725, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 439, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='forecast.weather.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /MapClick.php?lat=33.96746500000006&lon=-118.25679999999994 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BED2B7E388>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/Scraper/Clever scraper.py", line 17, in <module>
    page = requests.get(url2, proxies=proxies1, verify=False)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 510, in send
    raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='forecast.weather.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /MapClick.php?lat=33.96746500000006&lon=-118.25679999999994 (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001BED2B7E388>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it')))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You have a proxy, firewall or network related problem.

Comment: The error says `ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. So check if you can connect to proxy and then do a GET on destination host using something like netcat(https://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows/)

Comment: It is not a code issue, the code is fine